# Angular - Jasmine - Reset and reload component

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I want to spyOn a service more than once. To do that, I have used the `jasmine.getEnv().allowRespy(true);` statement.

When I do that, I figured out that I have to recreate my component
in order for changes to take place. I do that with:

```
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CardDisplayPageComponent);
component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
fixture.detectChanges();
```

I end up having a code like this:

```
 it('should have a datasource when cache has data', () => {
    spyOn(cacheService, 'getFromCache').and.returnValue([CARD_GENERIC_DATA_MOCK]);

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CardDisplayPageComponent);
    component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(component.dataSource).toBeTruthy();
  })


  it('should have a datasource when cache does not have data', () => {
    spyOn(cacheService, 'getFromCache').and.returnValue([undefined]);
    spyOn(seasonsFetchingService, 'getTransformedData').and.returnValue(of(CARD_PAGE_GENERIC_DATA_MOCK));

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CardDisplayPageComponent);
    component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(component.dataSource).toBeTruthy();
  })
```

Is there a way to avoid this duplication?

Answer (score 0):

Why to do that, make that services `public` in component `constructor` and then put spy as `component.cacheService`

```
it('should have a datasource when cache has data', () => {
    spyOn(component.cacheService, 'getFromCache').and.returnValue([CARD_GENERIC_DATA_MOCK]);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.dataSource).toBeTruthy();
  })


  it('should have a datasource when cache does not have data', () => {
    spyOn(component.cacheService, 'getFromCache').and.returnValue([undefined]);
    spyOn(component.seasonsFetchingService,'getTransformedData').and.returnValue(of(CARD_PAGE_GENERIC_DATA_MOCK));
    expect(component.dataSource).toBeTruthy();
  })
```

Something more to look for here [in my article](https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/testing-a-component-with-stub-services-and-spies-in-jasmine-1428d4242a49)

Comment: I did that but nothing changed. It seems the last spyOn call is not getting overwritten.

Comment: @AlexRasidakis Then there is some thing more going on in your code.  Also, with last spy call, do you mean `getTransformedData` ?? Can you put console log in component to verify the value returned from this service. You need to provide component code to help me figure that out

Comment: I inject the seasonsFetchingService into my component via injection token. I don't know if this is the reason for this behavior. No I meant that it seems that if I have called spyOn on to something then every next spyOn doesn't overwrite it.

Comment: @AlexRasidakis : Can you provide component code to help me understand this better ?